# Newton's Method: Order of Convergence of $f(x) = \sin(x) + 1$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I was given a problem that asked if it was possible to find the roots of $f(x) = sin(x) + 1$ using Newton's method, which by using an online calculator I had no problem showing. The next part asked what the order of convergence is and why.

Given that $f(r) = 0$, we want to find how many derivatives we need before we have a nonzero result when evaluated at $x = r$. In other words, $f(r) = f'(r) = ... = f^{(p)}(r) = 0$ and $f^{(p+1)}(r) \neq 0$. If this is the case, then the order of convergence is $p$. So in this particular problem $p = 1$, therefore, the order of convergence is 1 (linear).

Is this correct? Are there better ways of finding/understanding orders of convergence?

Comment: Note that $f(2x)=\cos^2x+\sin^2x+2\sin x\cos x=(\cos x+\sin x)^2$ so that the function is always positive and the roots are minima.

Comment: @LutzL Why is f(2x) significant? Both of the things you said are true about sin(x)+1 as well

Comment: Because I did not want to write $x/2$ everywhere. Note that I used the double angle formula of the sine. In the end, $f(x)=2\sin^2(\frac x2+\frac\pi4)$.